# how to store data in local?

Tags: android, kotlin, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have created an application that, given two input points, calls a function that draws a path, on a map, between the two points. I would now like to be able to implement the ability to click on the path and save it locally, in a list, so that I can retrieve it when necessary.

I'm a beginner with programming in kotlin and android, could you advise me how to do it?

I share below the function that I use to create the path in case it is useful.

```
    fun routePath(p1Latit: Double, p1Laong: Double, p2Latit: Double, p2Laong: Double){
        val roadManager: RoadManager = OSRMRoadManager(context, "lolloMaps")
        OSRMRoadManager.MEAN_BY_FOOT
        val waypoints = arrayListOf<GeoPoint>()
        val startPoint: GeoPoint = GeoPoint(p1Latit, p1Laong)
        waypoints.add(startPoint)
        val endPoint: GeoPoint = GeoPoint(p2Latit, p2Laong)
        waypoints.add(endPoint)
        mapView.overlays.forEach{
            if (it is Polyline && it.id == "Path"){
                mapView.overlays.remove(it)
            }
        }
        road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints)

        if (road.mStatus != Road.STATUS_OK){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error - status = " + road.mStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        val roadOverlay: Polyline = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road)
        roadOverlay.id = "Path"
        mapView.overlays.add(roadOverlay)
        mapView.invalidate()


        val nodeIcon: Drawable? = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(mapView.resources, R.drawable.marker_node, null)
        mapView.overlays.forEach{
            if (it is Marker && it.id == "Node"){
                mapView.overlays.remove(it)
            }
        }
        for (i: Int in road.mNodes.indices){
            val node: RoadNode = road.mNodes[i]
            val nodeMarker: Marker = Marker(mapView)
            nodeMarker.position = node.mLocation
            nodeMarker.icon = nodeIcon
            nodeMarker.title = "Passo $i"
            nodeMarker.id = "Node"
            mapView.overlays.add(nodeMarker)

            nodeMarker.snippet = node.mInstructions
            nodeMarker.subDescription = Road.getLengthDurationText(context,node.mLength, node.mDuration)
            // var icon: Drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_continue)
            // nodeMarker.image = icon
        }
    }
```

Comment: The recommended persistence for something like this is ROOM

Comment: You can store the waypoint list value as a global static final variable to guarantee that it persists during the current application session, despite orientation changes. When the app is being created/recreated and the list is not empty, the waypoints can be redrawn. You must draw the objects depending on the point data because the OsmDroid primitive objects and point data are independent. I suggest a map rather than a list so you can tag by id so you can have multiple waypoints.